# Prestashop custom product fields

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I am trying to add some custom fields on my prestashop backend and, when filled, to show up in frontend. Here are some examples of what I want to implement:
[image]

And here is the frontpage:

[image]

Searched everywhere but no results. I just need an idea or an example. Thank you!

Comment: One of clean solutions can be achieved through creating new Module, which will provide new tab in back-office product detail view, with separate database table and hooks for data output provided in front-office.

Comment: Here is a tutorial for adding tab in admin product http://blog.belvg.com/how-to-create-a-custom-product-tab-in-prestashop.html